# What do the gyro scales 250, 500, 2000 mean for the gyroscope : L3G4200D in the code

Tags: arduino, gyroscope

What do the gyro scales 250, 500, 2000 mean for the gyroscope : L3G4200D in the code below when setting up the gyroscope?

```
void gyroSetup() {    
    Wire.begin(); 
    GyroRotation.init(); 
    GyroRotation.setupL3G4200D(250); //250,500,2000
}
```

Comment: Don't you have any documentation that came with the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPS means degress per second.

You can find a lot of information from the vendor's site.  Did you get this gyro from Sparkfun ?

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/gyroscope
Check out this link to read a lot more about the use of gyros

Comment: Sorry for the late answer on your question, but yes the gyro was from Sparkfun.